# Run multiple instances of IBM BPM

Tags: ibm-bpm, websphere-process-server

I have the IBM Business Process Manager Advanced 7.5 installed.

**Question:**
Is it possible to install and run newer version - IBM BPM 8.5 **on the same machine**?

I worry about ports conflict (for example port 9043 to IBM Console).
Maybe I should ask how to change default port configuration?

Please help.

Comment: Yes, you can install both version on the same machine. If the previous installation is running, ports in conflict should be detected and changed, if you run from administrative user. Even if the ports will not be detected, you can change them later via admin console. If the admin console ports will be in conflict, simply stop other server and do the reconfiguration on the new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically it can be possible, however I suggest you do not do this as ibm bpm requires a lot of system resources to run and installing two versions of ibm bpm can make the system slower than ever before.

However I have seen multiple instances of same ibm bpm version running on a single cluster on server VM. This is practically stable and in use from considerable tenure.

PS. - I had administered a huge ibm bpm infra containing 80+ ibm bpm servers.

Answer (score 1):

As Gas already commented, in theory this is possible. But you have to be aware, that IBM BPM is not only using the specified ports for web access, it also uses ports for internal communication. In my opinion, this is not an easy task to get right.

On the other hand, the system requirements for IBM BPM are quite challenging for the server, if You want to run both instances in parallel, you should consider that your server will need to be capable. WebSphere is kind of greedy and not really designed to share its resources ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can run multiple versions of BPM on the same system. The primary concerns are going to be port conflict and OS system resources. Use the [BPMConfig](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFTBX_8.5.5/com.ibm.wbpm.imuc.sbpm.doc/topics/bpmcfg_create_prof_lin_db2.html?cp=SSFPJS_8.5.5&lang=en) to create a new profile and installation that is on different ports.  On my lab machines with VMs, I install all the BPM installs with the default ports and only have one (1) running at a time. If I need 2, I just spin up a new VM from the base template and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

By Default, the port conflicts are addressed by the WebSphere Application server code. If needed you can specify "initialPortAssignment"  for Dmgr, node and cluster members while creating the environment using BPMConfig command.  You can even specify specific port numbers using the

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFPJS_8.6.0/com.ibm.wbpm.ref.doc/topics/samplecfgprops.html

You can also provide Websphere options like "-startingPort starting_port | -portsFile ports_file_path | -defaultPorts" for Dmgr bpm.dmgr.profileOptions= and nodes   bpm.de.node.#.profileOptions  in the BPMConfig properties file.  For cluster members just have option to indicate the starting port.

REf: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/cs/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rxml_manageprofiles.html

I would not advise on changing the port numbers once you start using the BPM environment.

As indicated by others make sure you have enough resources if you are planning to run both environments at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am using two versions for evaluation. Port conflicts can be handled using server (WebSphere Integrated Solutions Console) console or BPMConfig utils.

Comment: Please provide with a comment only, if a comment can do the job, instead of posting an answer. Also See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: FYI.. Sir

"You must have 50 reputation to comment"